# Can cadvisor monitor ECS Windows Containers?

Tags: windows, containers, prometheus, amazon-ecs, cadvisor

I am trying to monitor my ECS Windows docker container via CAdvisor in combination with Prometheus/Grafana. I am not getting any reference which i can use to monitor my Windows Containers. My flow is something like below:-

```
- ECS Running with Windows Container in AWS
- Separate VM installed with Prometheus/Grafana 
- ECS host is installed with Windows-Expoter and i am getting data of my ECS host properly.
- Now i want container metrics as well which i guess cadvisor do , i have done that in linux , somehow issue with windows. And i guess we need to have cadvisor needs to be there on all ECS host to provide metrics in grafana.
```

Can someone help/route me to correct path for monitoring my Windows Containers.

Comment: I think not: https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2170